# how to open facebook from my application

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, native

i want to open the native Facebook application on a windows phone device,from my app

Now my question is, is it possible to check if that app has been installed,

on your device. and then open it with a navigation url, where you pass through the facebook id?

this is why:
we have a page on our application where one can see all the comments left by people handeling your current document, now if you tap on one of those users, you have a choice of either calling, mailin, or facebooking them if they have a facebook id on their profile.

so if i choose facebook, i want to open the native app(if installed), and send through the facebook id so that the app wil navigate to that persons profile.

how would i go about doing this? use the facbook c# sdk, or is there a task i can run?

if i find the link ill show it here, where in a apple dev enviroment it needs one line with a url to launch the app!?

so any links or tips will be appreciated.

regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay FOUND IT! at Last!

this is what i did!,

```
string myfbID = "54"; // facebook ID(my account)
var succes = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fb:"+ myfbID));
```

and the emulator asked if i want to install facebook.
you can get your own facebook id here [Just add your facebook name after the /](http://graph.facebook.com/)

hope this helps more people out there looking for this answer. i know i searched forever!